Status code 499 in Keycloak - Can't load login form
I have custom login in my realm on Keycloak. When I am connected to a domain network, everything works fine and I can see that login, but as soon as I am trying to access it outside the domain, I get the blank page with 499 status code on request for step1.html. I can see title of the app in the tab in browser.
Do I need to specify something in Content-Security-Policy in the realm security defenses?
I have tried setting that application domain in connect-src, script-src, default-src, allow-from and frame-ancestors but nothing helps. Or maybe do I need to configure something else? I don't believe it is firewall or something like that cause I am able to see that app title in the tab of the browser.
